# Setting :prologue in header args as elisp has "scope" problems when running (org-sbe), "wrong" `org-element-context`?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

To cut down on some repetitive boilerplate, I'm attempting to make my header arguments more "dynamic", but I have run into what I believe is a "scope" issue, that I cannot yet get around.

I would like to move the `:prologue` arg from the `cfg_*` source code blocks into the `:header-args:` of the parent section. Here's an MVE for the context:

```org
* CFG Generation
#+NAME: Platforms
| platform   | arch  | subarch | modelname             |
|------------+-------+---------+-----------------------|
| ar300m     | ath79 | generic | glinet_gl-ar300m-lite |
| archerC7V5 | ath79 | generic | tplink_archer-c7-v5   |

#+NAME: cfg-mk-dev-header
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var dev="devsoc" platforms=Platforms :tangle no
(format "Long String generated from the above table\n")
#+END_SRC

** Devices
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:  :noweb yes
:header-args+: :tangle (concat "cfg." (substring (org-element-property :name (org-element-context)) 3) ".gen")
:END:

*** ar300m - Device friendly name
#+NAME: cfg_ar300m
#+HEADER: :prologue (org-sbe cfg-mk-dev-header (dev '"ar300m"))
<<cfg_gcc_binutils>>
# ...
<<cfg_misc_options>>
#+END_SRC

*** archerC7V5 - Friendly Name
#+NAME: cfg_archerC7V5
#+HEADER: :prologue (org-sbe cfg-mk-dev-header (dev '"archerC7V5"))
...
```

The problematic line is:

```org
#+HEADER: :prologue (org-sbe cfg-mk-dev-header (dev '"ar300m"))
```

When I move this line into the `:header-args:`, and replace the static part `'"ar300m"` with `(substring (org-element-property :name (org-element-context)) 3)` like for `:tangle`, I then get

```
:prologue (org-sbe cfg-mk-dev-header (dev (substring (org-element-property :name (org-element-context)) 3)))
```

But when tangling the name-lookup fails, and I get the "default string" inserted in all config file.

Edit: Solved: I had the offset wrong-by-one (3 instead of 4).
Many thanks to @NickD for helping with the initial issue of "lisp max nesting", and then pointing me to the "bug", which requires to wrap the result of the name lookup in `(format "\"%s\"" ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `Lisp nesting` problem, make sure that your `cfg-make-device-header` block is **NOT** under the influence of those properties, otherwise when the block is evaluated to e.g. calculate the prologue of the other block, the headers apply to it as well, so you recurse infinitely.

And there is a quoting problem because... I don't know, I couldn't figure it out. It's probably a bug in `org-sbe` where it fails to protect its argument when it is a string, since the code block seems to return it without double quotes. But the following structure seems to work for me:

```org
#+name: cfg-make-device-header
#+begin_src shell :var dev="foo"
echo $dev
#+end_src

* Devices
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :noweb yes
:header-args+: :prologue (org-sbe "cfg-make-device-header" (dev (format "\"%s\"" (substring (org-element-property :name (org-element-context)) 3))))
:header-args+: :tangle (concat "config." (substring (org-element-property :name (org-element-context)) 3) ".gen")
:END:


** Device frobuzz
   #+name: frobuzz
   #+begin_src sh
   echo foo
   #+end_src
```

Note that the value of `dev` in the prologue has to be formatted with double quotes in order for this to work. But frankly, this seems way too fragile and debugging it is almost impossible: there are too many layers in the onion. I'd rethink the approach and probably replace the `cfg-make-devices-header` block with a lisp function, so as to avoid using `org-sbe`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Yes, `cfg-mk-dev-header` was further down, but still in the device section scope, and thus created the infinite nesting. Oops, Duh... Thanks there for pointing me in the right direction. :) It helped me get further. but revealed a follow-up problem. I've updated the post. Sorry for slightly shifting the goalpost. Could you have a look again, please?

Comment: I tried putting the whole `cfg-mk-dev-header` (i've shortened some names from my original, so that more "meat" fits into the lines in this post without scrolling) verbatim into the `:header-args: :prologue`, but then i don't know, how to get the `Platforms` table. That table is much longer IRL, and the plan is to have all subsections of the (long) `Devices` chapter autogenerated from another table listing device features. I plan to use an `:epilogue` in similar fashion

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I believe, i found/fixed my problem. ... The offset of "ar300m" in "cfg_ar300m" is 4, not 3 ... "Duh" again on my end. I'll edit the OP a bit later